# Error:Connection refused: no further information android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization, connection

when I use proxy on windows and create a new android project in android studio this error is raised:

> Error:Connection refused: no further information android studio

please help me to solve this error

Comment: I totally don't understand what are you asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because Google block Iran IP address.

I use American proxy and that be alright